# Virtually no bandwidth via Juniper QFX5100 switch

Tags: networking, juniper, junos

I have a Juniper QFX5100 with pretty much stock configs. I am using aggregated interfaces between them. When I use a cross over between the servers everything works fine and I get 10GB of bandwidth. When I go through the Juniper QFX5100 I barley get any bandwidth at all (iperf measures a few kb, scp doesn't even budge). I can't find anything in the logs that would show a reason.

Below is the QFX configs. ServerA is connected to XE-0/0/46 and ServerB is connected to XE-0/0/42.

```
set version 13.2X51-D10.6
set system host-name sw1
set system time-zone America/New_York
set system name-server 8.8.8.8
set system name-server 4.2.2.2
set system services ssh protocol-version v2
set system services netconf ssh
set system services web-management http port 1981
set system services dhcp traceoptions file dhcp_logfile
set system services dhcp traceoptions level all
set system services dhcp traceoptions flag all
set system syslog user * any emergency
set system syslog host 1.1.1.1 any any
set system syslog file messages any notice
set system syslog file messages authorization info
set system syslog file interactive-commands interactive-commands any
set system ntp server 74.207.249.60
set system ntp server 65.55.21.21
set system ntp server 74.118.152.85
set system ntp server 65.55.21.13
set chassis aggregated-devices ethernet device-count 20
set chassis auto-image-upgrade
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 description COGENT_UPLINK_1400A-TCURVE-ST01-Gi3-P14
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-UNTRUST
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 description COGENT_UPLINK_1400A-TCURVE-ST02-Gi3-P14
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-UNTRUST
set interfaces ge-0/0/2 description CONNECTED_TO_FW1-xe-0/0/2
set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-UNTRUST
set interfaces ge-0/0/3 description CONNECTED_TO_FW1-xe-0/0/3
set interfaces ge-0/0/3 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode trunk
set interfaces ge-0/0/3 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces ge-0/0/3 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members devlan
set interfaces ge-0/0/4 description CONNECTED_TO_TPLINK_PORT1_FOR_APC_DEVICES
set interfaces ge-0/0/4 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/4 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces ge-0/0/26 description vi_RAC
set interfaces ge-0/0/26 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/26 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces ge-0/0/28 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/28 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces ge-0/0/29 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/29 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces xe-0/0/30 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces xe-0/0/30 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members devlan
set interfaces xe-0/0/31 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces xe-0/0/31 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces xe-0/0/34 ether-options 802.3ad ae1
set interfaces xe-0/0/35 ether-options 802.3ad ae1
set interfaces ge-0/0/37 description RAC_web1
set interfaces ge-0/0/37 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/37 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces xe-0/0/38 description CONNECTED_TO_web1_p4p1
set interfaces xe-0/0/38 ether-options 802.3ad ae0
set interfaces xe-0/0/39 description CONNECTED_TO_web1_p4p2
set interfaces xe-0/0/39 ether-options 802.3ad ae0
set interfaces ge-0/0/40 description codd-a02-em3
set interfaces ge-0/0/40 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/40 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces ge-0/0/41 description codd-a02_iDRAC
set interfaces ge-0/0/41 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/41 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces xe-0/0/42 description codd-a02-em1
set interfaces xe-0/0/42 ether-options 802.3ad ae2
set interfaces xe-0/0/43 description codd-a02-em2
set interfaces xe-0/0/43 ether-options 802.3ad ae2
set interfaces ge-0/0/44 description codd-b01-em3
set interfaces ge-0/0/44 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/44 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces ge-0/0/45 description codd-b01-DRAC
set interfaces ge-0/0/45 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/45 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces xe-0/0/46 description codd-b01-em1
set interfaces xe-0/0/46 ether-options 802.3ad ae3
set interfaces xe-0/0/47 description codd-b01-em2
set interfaces xe-0/0/47 ether-options 802.3ad ae3
set interfaces ae0 description SERVER_web1
set interfaces ae0 aggregated-ether-options lacp active
set interfaces ae0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ae0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces ae1 description SERVER2
set interfaces ae1 aggregated-ether-options lacp active
set interfaces ae1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ae1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members FW-TRUST
set interfaces ae2 description codd-b01-internal-network
set interfaces ae2 mtu 9000
set interfaces ae2 aggregated-ether-options lacp active
set interfaces ae2 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ae2 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members SILENT_WEB_INTERNAL
set interfaces ae3 description codd-a02-internal-network
set interfaces ae3 mtu 9000
set interfaces ae3 aggregated-ether-options lacp active
set interfaces ae3 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ae3 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members SILENT_WEB_INTERNAL
set interfaces vlan unit 1 family inet address 144.10.10.11/27
set snmp description FW1
set snmp location PHL
set snmp view jweb-view-all oid .1 include
set snmp community T_CURVE view jweb-view-all
set snmp community T_CURVE authorization read-only
set snmp community T_CURVE clients 1.1.1.1/32
set forwarding-options storm-control-profiles default all
set routing-options static route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 144.10.10.10
set protocols dcbx interface all
set protocols lldp interface all
set protocols lldp-med interface all
set protocols igmp-snooping vlan all
set vlans FW-TRUST vlan-id 1
set vlans FW-TRUST l3-interface irb.1
set vlans FW-UNTRUST vlan-id 2
set vlans SILENT_WEB_INTERNAL vlan-id 80
set vlans default vlan-id 99
set vlans default l3-interface irb.99
set vlans devlan vlan-id 201
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the MTU was the same on the switch as it was on the servers. The MTU on the switch needed to be a bit higher. Setting the MTU to 9214 did the trick.

Comment: The problem is that some vendors use "MTU" for the maximum L2 frame size which is incorrect. "MTU" specifies the maximum L3 packet size. The maximum frame size needs to be 28 bytes larger (or 32 with 802.1Q) to accomodate L2 overhead.